# How to use JSON-RPC in C++ in Linux?

Tags: transactions, json-rpc

Which library I must use for JSON? Where is RPC call example ?
How to use RPC of bitcoind or bitcoin-cli? or better **Electrum** API to get all new (maybe pending) transactions which appears in Bitcoin net?

Comment: Like popen()? Or system()?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to interact with bitcoind using C++?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/21770/how-to-interact-with-bitcoind-using-c)

Answer (score 1):

> How to use RPC of bitcoind or bitcoin-cli?

1. bitcoind - bitcoin deamon = core value of the software (bitcoind -printtoconsole -debug=1)
2. bitcoin-cli - bitcoin command line interface = allow you to "query' the blockchain that you had download previously with bitcoind. (bitcoin-cli getinfo)

So bitcoind provide the RPC "interface" in which you can query with bitcoin-cli 
(or a library in c++ you will find...).
You must run bitcoind before using bitcoin-cli.

Basically bitcoin-cli communicate with your node bitcoind so in other word your current blockchain state.

bitcoin-qt - Graphical bitcoin software = bitcoind + graphical interface 

(You can find a graphical console embedded in which you will use bitcoin-cli command)

Answer (score 1):

Even though it is a C library, you could use [Jansson](https://jansson.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) in C++ apps, too. See: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/API_reference_(JSON-RPC)#C

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you chose C++
If you are going to build something where you need the speed of C++ then understandably stick with it.
Otherwise to simply perform some RPC calls use something simpler like python or PHP.

Here is a tutorial on how to do RPC calls via python:
[Bitcoin & Blockchain Programming #007 – RPCs via Python](http://blog.cryptoiq.ca/?p=347)

And via PHP:
[Bitcoin & Blockchain Programming #005 – RPCs via PHP](http://blog.cryptoiq.ca/?p=261)

Answer (score 1):

Your direct question is about a fine JSON-RPC library in C++, and the direct answer to it is:

- [libjson-cpp](https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp) &
- [libjson-rpc-cpp](https://github.com/cinemast/libjson-rpc-cpp)

But if I wanna target your intention, there is a well-developed wrapper for Bitcoind-json/rpc interface [here](https://github.com/minium/bitcoin-api-cpp). It will save you massive time!